# Nextcloud Uploader

Tags: php, web-frontend, owncloud, nextcloud

I just got some questions, maybe some of you can answer.

The benefit by Nextcloud / Owncloud and so on is more than just uploading taking files with you and so on.
It does version the files, make them downloadable - as well secure behind.

It would be benefitial for me and most everyone who is dealing with the Question:

**"How to upload documents, link them in some kind of Database (which main purpose is to operate with information) and versioning, saving, editing and so on does not need to be implemented by me / others, because it is handled by Nextcloud (in my case prefered)?"**

Is there any script outside, or maybe some kind of plugin to have that benefit?

---

In my vision I would need:

1. One "Drag and Drop" Area for Documents / Pictures etc.

   - This should have a hidden field, which is filled with a id, with which the system can identify the file.
2. a onetime Link (with retention of that link by one day or so) what is generated by php (could also be a script) and generates a share Link for given id.
3. (not needed since now, but nice to have:) some script as in 2, where versions of some given File should be viewed.

---

Some solution could be:

something similar to an "iframe" for a shared link with public upload.
But Im not very happy of using IFrames... Something better would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag & Drop is available in the Web UI. For additional meta data, use a hook mechanism on `postCreate (\OCP\Files\Node $node)` within a custom app/module you'd need to deploy. For hooks, see https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/app/hooks.html. 
   About meta data: you don't need to store them in a database necessarily, you can also use custom WebDav properties. I wrote a blog post about it recently: https://medium.com/@mathiasconradt/how-to-assign-custom-meta-data-to-your-documents-on-nextcloud-23356cf3f926
2. Links with a time limit to be valid can be generated manually via Web UI. If you need it automated on upload, use the same approach as in (1): hook mechanism that listens to file creations, as part of a custom app.
3. at the moment, you can only restore old versions. I think you cannot diff/view them. Would require a custom app.

General info on how to write your own module / app: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/app/index.html